# debug nhibernate original release

Tags: nhibernate, debugging, pdb-files

I downloaded the binaries of nhibernate from their original site,
if i get the source code, can i debug their binaries??
what I mean : I don't want to rebuild the source code and take the binaries to the project
and then debug them.
BTW they don't provide a pdb files with their binaries.
i just want to link my source code to the already exist binaries?

when i try to open the modules window and choose to load a symbol file : Nhibernate.Pdb
i get this message :

### A matching symbol file was not found in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the symbols from http://www.symbolsource.org/

Comment: they have only  the version 3.0 which is also Alpha!   
anyway the site is greate, Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

PDBs are provided starting with NHibernate 3.0.

Comment: I have the 2.1.2 version, and i can't move forward to 3.0 especially it is alpha version.